# Problem With NSArray

Tags: iphone, sdk, nsarray

i have the following code

```
@interface TestYourInfoViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIImageView * questionImage;
NSArray *historyQuestions;
int questionHistoryNo;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImageView * questionImage;

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *historyQuestions;
@property int questionHistoryNo;
-(IBAction)solution:(id)sender;

@end




    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSArray* array = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    historyQuestions = array;
    historyQuestions=UmRandomOrder(49, 1, 0);



     questionImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"h%@.jpg",[self.historyQuestions objectAtIndex:0]]];
    [array release];
     [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}


-(IBAction)solution:(id)sender{

     questionHistoryNo= questionHistoryNo+1;
    questionImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"h%@.jpg",[self.historyQuestions objectAtIndex:questionHistoryNo]]];


}
```

when i press the action button it gives me exception in the line [self.historyQuestions objectAtIndex:questionHistoryNo]

i believe the problem is in the nsarray somehow but i don't know what is it.. the exception is 
can anyone help me ..

Comment: Where does questionHistoryNo come from? Why are you adding 1 to it before using it? Perhaps you shouldn't (because arrays are 0-indexed).

Comment: The error message might actually be pretty useful.

Comment: Have your check how many object there are in the array? Are you maybe out of bounds?

Comment: You need to show us the code for `UmRandomOrder` as this could be the culprit if it returns an autoreleased object. Also, you can remove the `array` variable and all lines referencing it as you aren't using it other than creating and immediately destroying it. Also, post the exact exception message.

Comment: That array variable makes no sense at all.

Comment: [First result of googling `UmRandomOrder`](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HowToGenerateARandomOrder) (I don't know if it is actually related)...

Comment: UmRandomOrder  is a class to get random array which is ok

Comment: if i put nslog for the array in the viewDidLoad it give a result put and the same code in the button when put in viewDidLoad it goes well the problem happen when goes to the action button as if it's release from memory which i doubt but it may happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually DarkDust has it correct: the source code for UMRandomOrder shows that it properly returns an autorelease NSMutableArray.  So, just change the first three lines of your viewDidLoad from:

```
NSArray* array = [[NSArray alloc]init];
historyQuestions = array;
historyQuestions=UmRandomOrder(49, 1, 0);
```

to just:

```
  self.historyQuestions=UmRandomOrder(49, 1, 0);
```

And you'll be fine.

To be specific, there's no need to alloc/init/assign an array you're about to write over, and by using the property setter (self.historyQuestions = ), you'll automatically do a proper retain, as well as avoiding a potential memory leak. That also explains why it works in viewDidLoad (the autoreleased UmRandomOrder is still valid), but not in the action button (it has since been released).

Comment: thanks it worked.. actually i need to understand what the deffrence between call it by the word (self) and without it cause i think that was all the problem here